the union of two spheres in one point isn't a topological manifold
I want to prove that two spheres that their intersection is a single point it isn't a topological manifold. For that I think that i read a topological manifold is local connected in every point and I think that in the intersection point it isn't local connected but i'm not sure if it is true and i don't know how to formalize it. (I'm new with that)
Thank you for the help.

Does this answer your question? Is it true that the wedge of two manifolds is not a manifold? (found using the search engine) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630880 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527707
